# Remove actionButton() via removeUI() function in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use the `removeUI()` function from the shiny package but I'm having some difficulty removing particular elements. Below is an example of this problem, slightly modified from the example in `help(removeUI)`. Specifically, the commented out line containing `textInput(` was replaced by `actionButton(` instead.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("rmv", "Remove UI"),
      actionButton("txt", "This is no longer useful")
      #textInput("txt", "This is no longer useful")
    )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$rmv, {
    removeUI(
      selector = "div:has(> #txt)"
    )
  })
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

While the components of `textInput()` can be removed, this method does not work for removing analogous components using `actionButton()`. I'm unsure as to why, since the logic of the jQuery selector seems the same in this case.

I also tried changing `selector = "div:has(> #txt)"` to `selector = "button:has(> #txt)"`, thinking that the jQuery search would apply to the `button` elements, but again to no avail.

EDIT: found a solution. Wrapping `actionButton("txt", "This is no longer useful")` with a `div()` puts the action button into the `div<>` block, so the search will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First some general stuff, every element within the page must have unique `id` you cannot use the same name for multiple elements as you're doing for `actionButton` and `textInput`. This rule applies to all HTML pages on the web.
- Regarding the question, I have written a small function which will allow you to collect the elements which match a certain pattern

---

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("rmv", "Remove UI"),
    actionButton("txt", "This is no longer useful"),
    textInput("txt2", "This is no longer useful")
  )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  getInputs <- function(pattern){
    reactives <- names(reactiveValuesToList(input))
    reactives[grep(pattern,reactives)]
  }

  observeEvent(input$rmv, {

    vals <- getInputs("txt")
    vals <- paste0("#",vals)

    removeUI(
      selector = vals,
      multiple = T
    )
  })
}
# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the `reactiveValuesToList()` function. That was what I needed to locate the input names.